# Runtime error with 0MQ Haskell binding: getIntOpt: interrupted (Interrupted system call)

Tags: haskell, zeromq

With the below function is based on the 0MQ Haskell bindings. I get an error at runtime. The error says `getIntOpt: interrupted (Interrupted system call)` and the program stops.

It probably has to do something with command line options that I use and then discard because of criterion?

Edit: found out that I get the error also when I leave my own code with cmdArgs away.
There is actually a much more interesting problem behind. See last paragraph [here](http://www.zeromq.org/docs:2-1-upgrade). But I have still no clue how to deal with it effectively.

```
    sendReceive :: B.ByteString -> IO ()
    sendReceive datastring = withContext 1 $ \context -> do
         withSocket context Req $ \requester -> do
            --putStrLn "Connecting ..."
            connect requester "tcp://192.168.35.84:5559"
            let tryOnePing (!c, !f) i = do
                send requester datastring []
                --putStrLn "Sent ..."
                r <- receive requester []
                --putStrLn "Received ..."
                return $ case B.unpack r of
                   datastring -> (c+1, f)
                   _ -> (c, f+1)
            (c,f) <- foldM tryOnePing (0,0) [1 .. 1000]
            -- c and f are not used in this example
            return ()

main = do
     n <- cmdArgsRun strlen
     let datastring  = B.pack (take (byte n) $ randomRs ('a','z') (mkStdGen 3))
     putStrLn "Starting..."
     withArgs [] $ defaultMain [bench "sendReceive" $ whnfIO (sendReceive datastring)]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bindings use the FFI helper function `throwErrnoIfMinus1_`, which throws an error from `errno` if the wrapped function returns `-1`. The new zeromq library expects the caller to properly handler `EINTR`, which isn't happening here.

You could ask the library maintainer to use `throwErrnoIfMinus1Retry_`, which retries the wrapped function automatically if it returns `-1` and `errno` is set to `EINTR`.

It looks like you can catch the `IOException`, but I don't know how to get at the value of `errno`, even though it is stored within it (unless you want to import `GHC.IO.Exception`, which seems a it shady to me).

Comment: Thanks. Can I fix here something with `throw` or `catch` from here: http://haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.12.1/html/libraries/base/Control-Exception.html ??

Comment: You can catch the `IOException`, but I couldn't find a standard way to get the `errno` value out of it without importing `GHC.IO.Exception` - you wouldn't want to retry the action automatically unless `errno` was `EINTR`.

Comment: To bad. At high messaging frequencies it happens quite often. Eventually this could render the whole Haskell binding useless for real-world applications.

Comment: It shouldn't be hard to fix the binding: https://github.com/twittner/zeromq-haskell I recommend trying it to see if my suggestion was correct :-)

Comment: Or at minimum you could file a bug with the maintainer, so the maintainer knows there is something to fix.